# Data returning from api call through service to component is an object and seems to need to be an Array for Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, observable

I have data returned to me that works just fine

working data is

`data: Array(16)`

Data that is NOT working is like this

`data:  Menu1Items: Array(5)  > 0 { .... }    etc`

I am using Angular 5, and so service returns data like this

```
  .map((response: Response) => {
            return response;
```

Then the component intercepts it and console.log works fine

```
this.arsSevice.getMenu()
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.testing = result; 
                console.log('menu',result);
            })
```

problem is with the data,  this screenshot shows the problem, i just don't understand how to fix it with the object vs array?

error message ONLY because of the HTML TEMPLATE

`Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

HTML Template

```
<li *ngFor="let item of testing">
```

Image showing that a call that is similar in architecture with html template loop,  component , service  the working call is the BOTTOM , `component`  notice the different compared to the one called `menu` that I'm having trouble with?

[image]

Comment: How can your data possibly change? You must be modifying it somewhere, please provide all the code needed to reproduce the issue, or better yet, create a demo that showcases the issue.

Comment: He seems to be showing an example (I think )  of 1 that works (a different call I assume) to one that doesn't work   -  Certainly not explained very well, but I stumbled across this and the answer selected did help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set testing = result.data, and iterate through that.

```
this.arsSevice.getMenu()
        .subscribe(
            result => {
                this.testing = result.data; 

            })
```

this will give you access to the array in 'data'

I tried to change the shape of the data, and this worked for me.  Hopefully it works for you...

```
var data={
      menu1Items:[{key:"boo", key2:"hoo"}],
      menu2Items:[{key:"boo2", key2:"hoo2"}]
    }
    var tempData:any[]=[];
    for(var key in data){
      if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        tempData.push(data[key]);
      }
    }
    this.data = tempData;
}
```

In your template:

```
<ul *ngFor="let menu of data ">
  <li>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let menuItem of menu">
          {{menuItem.key}} / {{ menuItem.key2}}       
      </ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, I did that, no luck .    The data is different notice the screenshot.   the working service /component has the data in an array  , but look at the data that i'm getting back in the menu  ...

Comment: Is GetMenu is a different call from the 'working array' or is it the same one?  Why does one have a status of 'fail' and the other success?  The Menu Items are also arrays of objects, so you would need to iterate through each menu array as well.  Have you tried with two loops?

Comment: @Farasi78   doing a google search and stumbled here.  I have a similar problem as that guy asking the question.   I have an array of objects that I need to iterate over.  I am not in front of my code at the moment, I need to get back to my computer with my code and post a question I guess.  Wondering of an example from that angular code on how to really loop over each array?   can you show an example?

Comment: this worked for me.   I do something like     `customers : any;`  then  customers = result.data["customers"]

Answer (score 0):

With HttpClient angular automatically parses the reponse into an object. It doesn't know what type of object that is, so it's just a normal object that doesn't know its array properties.

> That's because while HttpClient parsed the JSON response into an Object, it doesn't know what shape that object is.

But you can tell angular what type the returning object is so it is cast properly. For example if you get back an array of strings you could do something like this.

```
return this.http.get<string[]>(apiUrl)
```

You can read more [here](https://angular.io/guide/http), they are describing a similar problem, just with a little different structure.